# Laravel can't send mail Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailgun.org

Tags: php, laravel-4

```
Mail::send('emails.test_layout', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('myemail@gmail.com', 'test')->subject('test request');
});
```

i'am getting this error:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailgun.org
```

how to fix this?

using laravel-4

Comment: Also having the same issue!

Comment: Please edit your question and append the mail configuration file `app/config/mail.php`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such problem with mailgun. The problem might be with your internet server provider blocking outbound SMTP traffics (contact them for this issue) or you might have issue with your network connections especially with firewall settings.